# Issue when appending to file

Tags: python

I have the following code where i want to add some text to the already existing file.

```
with open("travellerList.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(ReplyTraveller)
myfile.close()
```

But I am getting:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The error points to the n in the open command. Can someone help me understand where I am making mistake in the above snippet?

Comment: what dou you have in ReplyTraveller ? Ther is a __string__ method on it?

Comment: The code by itself is fine. The Syntax error has to have some other reason. Can you show a little more of your program?

Comment: you don't need close the file when using with statement. It will be closed automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `with` syntax was only fully enabled in Python 2.6.

You must be using Python 2.5 or earlier:

```
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Nov 28 2010, 19:00:19) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open("travellerList.txt", "a") as myfile:
<stdin>:1: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    with open("travellerList.txt", "a") as myfile:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Use `from __future__ import with_statement` in Python 2.5 to enable the syntax there:

```
>>> from __future__ import with_statement
>>> with open("travellerList.txt", "a") as myfile:
...     pass
...
```

From the [`with` statement specification](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

> *New in version 2.5.*
>
> [...]
>
> **Note**: In Python 2.5, the `with` statement is only allowed when the `with_statement` feature has been enabled. It is always enabled in Python 2.6.

The point of using a file as a context manager is that it'll be closed automatically, so your `myfile.close()` call is redundant.

For Python 2.4 or earlier you are out of luck, I'm afraid. You'd have to use a `try`- `finally` statements instead:

```
myfile = None
try:
    myfile = open("travellerList.txt", "a")
    # Work with `myfile`
finally:
    if myfile is not None:
        myfile.close()
```

Comment: And if using Python 2.5, then `from __future__ import with_statement` may be of some use...

Comment: It's worth noting that 2.5 (or worse, earlier) are *very* old versions of Python that are not supported any more. It would be worth upgrading to at least 2.7.

Comment: I think you are correct, unfortunately, my organization is stuck at version 2.4 or something. We are ancient :(

Comment: @Lattyware: many long-term-support Linux distributions use older versions, leaving a lot of people stuck on those.

Comment: any way to find a solution without upgrading?

Comment: @RaheelAliBaloch: `import sys; print sys.version` to be certain about what version you are stuck with.

Comment: @RaheelAliBaloch: Added the old way of ensuring that a file is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `myfile.close()`.  This works fine:

```
with open("travellerList.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(ReplyTraveller)
```

the `with` block will automatically close `myfile` at the end of the block.  When you try to close it yourself, it's actually already out of scope.

However, it seems you're using a python older than 2.6, where the `with` statement was added.  Try upgrading python, or using `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top of your file if you can't upgrade.

One last thing, idk what ReplyTraveller is, but you're naming it like a class, it needs to be a string to write it to a file.